# How can I set the default editor as nano on my Mac?

Tags: shell, macos, editors, nano

I have vim as default editor on my Mac and every time I run commands on Mac terminal, it automatically opens "vim".

How can I set up "nano" instead and make sure the terminal will open "nano" every time is needed?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Set the `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` environment variables to `nano`.

If you use `bash`, this is easiest done by editing your `~/.bashrc` file and adding the two following lines:

```
export EDITOR=nano
export VISUAL="$EDITOR"
```

to the bottom of the file. If the file does not exist, you may create it.  Note that macOS users should probably modify the `~/.bash_profile` file instead, as the abovementioned file is not used by default when starting a `bash` shell on this system.

If you use some other shell, modify that shell's startup files instead (e.g. `~/.zshrc` for `zsh`).

You should set both variables as some tools use one, and others may use the other.

You will need to restart your terminal to have the changes take effect.

Comment: This is a great solution! How can we get the name of other editors for this purpose?

Comment: @BenRacicot The editors installed by default on macOS are `nano`, `vi`/`vim`, and `ed` (a very basic line-editor). If you install other editors for used in the shell, e.g. through Homebrew, then you would know what they are (since you installed them).

Comment: Yes, only the common issue online is swapping text edit as default for Sublime Text 3. However, `export EDITOR=Sublime Text` does nothing.

Comment: @BenRacicot Any command that uses e.g. `$EDITOR` will use it as a command. You would set it to the command that you use to launch Sublime from the command line. If the command contains spaces, then it has to be quoted.

Comment: @BenRacicot this answer may help if you're trying to use a GUI application like Sublime Text https://stackoverflow.com/a/3539630/370407

Comment: For macOS Big Sur and up you'll need to put it in the `~/.zshrc` file, as Big Sur doesn't use bash anymore. (this includes macOS Monterey)

Comment: @Mint It will depend on whatever shell the user is using, not what shell is the default on the system. Note that it is possible to install various shells on macOS, including moderns `bash` releases. I will however update my answer to say that it depends on the shell.

Answer (score 10):

I had this same challenge when setting up my new MacBook Pro.

To elaborate more on [Kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/501863/390383)

To switch to your editor of choice (say `nano`) you will need to add the following lines to your `~/.zshrc` file if your default shell is `zsh` or `~/.bash_profile` if your default shell is `bash`:

```
export EDITOR=nano
export VISUAL="$EDITOR"
```

However, a simpler approach to do this will be to use the `echo` command to insert them into your `~/.zshrc` file if your default shell is `zsh`:

```
echo 'export EDITOR=nano' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'export VISUAL="$EDITOR"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

OR `~/.bashrc` if your default shell is `bash`:

```
echo 'export EDITOR=nano' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export VISUAL="$EDITOR"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Run the command below to activate the new configuration:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

OR

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

If you need to switch to other editors of choice you can replace `nano` with your preferred editor:

- Vim - `vim`
- Vi - `vi`

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 1):

The answer suggested by @Kusalananda doesnt work with a default install of Catalina.

Apple has changed the shell from bash to zsh as default in Catalina.

You need to rename your `.bash_profile` as `.zprofile`.

Then it works.