# How to debug why iTerm2 is loading SublimeText instead of VSCode as the default editor when I click iTerm2 links?

Tags: editors

I read [How can I set the default editor as nano on my Mac?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/501862/how-can-i-set-the-default-editor-as-nano-on-my-mac) and tried setting my default editor in `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, and `.zshrc` (how do I tell which one I'm using)? After adding to each of these files, I restarted my iTerm2, but still picking up the old editor....

### `.bashrc`

```
# export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib"
# export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include"

export LLVM_HOME=/usr/local/opt/llvm
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LLVM_HOME/lib

PS1="$ "
. "$HOME/.cargo/env"
export EDITOR=code
export VISUAL="$EDITOR"
```

### `.bash_profile`

```
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc

. "$HOME/.cargo/env"
export EDITOR=code
export VISUAL="$EDITOR"
```

### `.zshrc`

```
alias subl="/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
source ~/.bash_profile
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"
export GOPATH="$HOME/go"
export PATH="$GOPATH/bin:$PATH"
# export PATH="~/.cargo/bin:$PATH"
```

### Question

How do I specify to use `code` (VSCode cli tool) to open the VSCode editor, it is still opening SublimeText (which I may have configured *somewhere* a long time ago, I don't know where to look). How do I debug this?

Hoping to be able to click on these source code files in iTerm2 and have it open VSCode in my current context.

[image]